# Permanently forget the job if failed

Tags: laravel

I have a long-running job in which, if failed I want to permanently delete it totally so that a job should not be retried or attempted.

here is what i try

```
//queue.php

  'database-large-reports-on-web-server' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'ten_minuite_queue_web_server',
            'retry_after' => 1800,
        ],
```

here is how i dispatch the job

```
OrdersExportJob::dispatch()->onConnection('database-large-reports-on-web-server');
```

```
// myJob
class OrdersExportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
   
    public $timeout = 400;
    public $tries = 1;

    public function handle() { ... }
}
```

```
//My supervisor configuration

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/ymyapp/artisan queue:work database-large-reports-on-web-server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=9999
```

Result: the job kept reattempted after it gets failed.

Answer (score 3):

how about manual delete job on fail?

```
class OrdersExportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    // ....

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->delete();
    }
```

`delete()` is part of `use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job`, and can be accessable if `Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue` trait is used

Comment: failed() is not called at all  , laravel 7.x

Comment: @Seyid, may be you dispatch it with `dispatchNow()`? As it mentoned here - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs - `failed` will not call in ths case. Anyway, you can listen for failed event as described here - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#failed-job-events - and delete it `$event->job->delete()` after proper type check

Answer (score 1):

You should remove $tries option from your job, You do not need it if you do not want your job to be re-attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique id to every job, and storing a list of every id you’ve seen in the db.
Then, discard every job that’s in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception in the job and `$maxExceptions = 1` the job will fail and not be reattempted.

```
class OrdersExportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
   
    public $maxExceptions = 1;

    public function handle() { ... }
}
```

When you want to stop and not retry.

```
throw new \RuntimeException('Stop the job and go to the failed queue');
```

You'll then see the job on the failed queue with this command:

```
php artisan queue:failed
```